# Which model to use for analyzing complex expenditure survey data (Regression, ML ...)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, survey, survey-weights

I have a sample of $15,000$ households (survey on households' expenditures) of which only 3% have zero consumption. I would like to explain electricity expenditures (**Elec_exp_hh**) by income (**TAExp_hh**) and other categorical variables (sex of housheholds, location...etc).

**Given the results below, what model should I use ?**

Tobit model to account for the zeros which are very few or should I remove them from the data set and use OLS, quantile regression, ML techniques or another method. The zeros are true zeros (of non consumption).

Here are the steps I followed:
I runned a linear regression of Electricity expenditures on income and location :

[image]

[image]

Here are the results of residuals:

[image]

I also checked OLS assumptions.

I ran the same regression but with removing the few zero observations and here are the results:

[image]

When I transform my dependent and independent variables into *log* (add to 0 to all observations for the dependent variable before log transformation), the results are as follows :

1. When 0 observations are kept in the sample :

[image]

2. When I removed the 0 observations before transforming in log:

[image]

Comment: It seems that there is a lot going on in your post. I think you have a higher chance to get help if you ask fewer specific questions in a clearer way.